# mongoose embed document in query with Node

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregate-functions, mongoose-schema

I have 2 schemas:

User
Properties

I want to query the properties collection and add the user into the property document as a new field (possibly through $addFields)

The properties object has a userId string attribute that matches the _id in the User schema, how can I do this with aggregate or a simple find?

I am currently doing this:

```
Property.aggregate([
        { $skip : parseInt(req.query.skip,10) },
        { $limit : parseInt(req.query.limit,10) },
        { $sort : { "address.town": 1, "address.line1": 1 }},
        {
          $lookup: {
              from: "users",
              localField: "userId.str",
              foreignField: "_id.str",
              as: "landlord"
          }
        }
      ]
```

But this just returns all users in the landlord array, not the one that matches the user_id and userId fields.

To be clear, the Property Schema has a **userId: String** attribute.
I want to match this with the **Users Schema _id** attribute.

Comment: try removing `.str` ind "userId.str" and "_id.str"

Comment: No, that returns an empty array.